# Execute Request Repeatedly for Async Call Until it meets correct response in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

using 70 HTTP requests inside transaction controller in which one request response we have to match the text. If text matches we have to execute that request repeatedly otherwise control will move to next request.
How we can achieve this in JMeter?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the relevant [JMeter's PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to check whether the response matches the given text. The PostProcessor choice depends on the response nature, i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) for HTML, [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) for JSON, [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) for XML/XHTML, etc.
2. Once you get either a match or a number of matches you can put the request you need to repeat under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-count-retries-as-a-single-request-in-jmeter) and come up with the proper expression which will exit the [while loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop) once there will be no matches.